# Attempt to invoke virtual method on a null object reference. ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, android-room

the compiler gives this error

`Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.util.ArrayList com.example.schedule.Mon2Fragment.Text_getter()' on
a null object reference`

Here is my code:

```
class MyAsyncTaskOthers2 extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>{

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        Database db = App.getInstance().getDatabase();
        if(!db.classDao().doesGroupExist(intent.getStringExtra(Others.EXTRA_DATA))){
            ClassEntity new_group=new ClassEntity();
            new_group.id_of_a_group= intent.getStringExtra(Others.EXTRA_DATA);
            new_group.monday= mon2Fragment.Text_getter(); // It points on this line
            db.classDao().insert(new_group);
        }
        else{
            db.classDao().update(mon2Fragment.Text_getter(),intent.getStringExtra(Others.EXTRA_DATA));

        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Here is Text_getter method:

```
public ArrayList<String> Text_getter() {
    ArrayList<String> arr=new ArrayList<>();
    arr.add((String) textView1.getText());
    arr.add((String) textView2.getText());
    arr.add((String) textView3.getText());
    arr.add((String) textView4.getText());
    arr.add((String) textView5.getText());
    arr.add((String) textView6.getText());
    arr.add((String) textView7.getText());
    arr.add((String) textView8.getText());
    return arr;
}
```

I initialized an arraylist

```
ArrayList<String> arr=new ArrayList<>();
```

As you can see above, I do not know why there is NPE error.

Comment: `mon2Fragment` is `null`, not the ArrayList.

Comment: `ArrayList` is the return type of `Text_getter()`.

Comment: I doesn't show that @Guy